# Highlighting text in PDF file using R

Tags: r, pdf

I wanted to highlighted some text in a PDF document using R. I want to search a PDF document for some text and highlight the text if found. I searched for packages which could do this.

`pdftools` and `pdfsearch` are packages which help in handling PDF documents. These packages mainly handle converting pdf to text and doing any sort of manipulation.

Is there a way in which we can highlight a PDF document using R?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288400/highlight-text-in-a-pdf-with-python

Comment: Thanks @MartinValgur. I'll see if there are better alternatives. Otherwise calling a python code from R would maybe solve my problem.

Comment: I ended up writing my own package to do this. If anyone needs this functionality its available on my [github page](https://github.com/Swechhya/pdfUtils).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to highlight some keywords in a PDF with the following code. There are four steps :

1. Save wikipedia page to PDF;
2. Convert the PDF to word document with the Word Software (There is an OCR!!);
3. Highlight the keywords in the word document;
4. Save the word document as PDF.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(DescTools)
library(pagedown)

#############################################
#### Step 1 : Save wikipedia page as PDF ####
#############################################
chrome_print(input = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat", 
             output = "C:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf")

path_PDF <- "C:\\Text_PDF_Cat.pdf"
path_Word <- "C:\\Text_PDF_Cat.docx"

################################################################
#### Step 2 : Convert PDF to word document with OCR of Word ####
################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)
doc_Selection <- wordApp$Selection()

######################################################
#### Step 3 : Highlight keywords in word document ####
######################################################
move_To_Beginning_Doc <- function(doc_Selection)
{
  doc_Selection$HomeKey(Unit = wdConst$wdStory) # Need DescTools for wdConst$wdStory
}

highlight_Text_Regex_Word <- function(doc,
                                      doc_Selection,
                                      words_To_Highlight, 
                                      colorIndex = 7,
                                      nb_Max_Word = 100)
{
  for(i in words_To_Highlight)
  {
    move_To_Beginning_Doc(doc_Selection)
    
    for(j in 1 : nb_Max_Word)
    {
      doc_Selection$Find()$Execute(FindText = i, MatchCase = FALSE)
      doc_Selection_Range <- doc_Selection$Range()
      doc_Selection_Range[["HighlightColorIndex"]] <- colorIndex
    }
  }
}

highlight_Text_Regex_Word(doc, doc_Selection,
                          words_To_Highlight = c("cat", "domestic", "quick"), 
                          colorIndex = 7, nb_Max_Word = 100)
  
###############################################
#### Step 4 : Convert word document to pdf ####
###############################################
path_PDF_Highlighted <- "C:\\Text_PDF_Cat_Highlighted.pdf"
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs(path_PDF_Highlighted, FileFormat = 17) # FileFormat = 17 saves as .PDF
doc$Close()
wordApp$Quit() # quit wordApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to highlight text in a PDF file with the following code :

```
library(reticulate)

conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "PyMuPDF") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "PyMuPDF", python_version = "3.7.16")
  reticulate::conda_install(envname = "PyMuPDF", packages = "PyMuPDF", pip = TRUE)
}

reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "PyMuPDF")
path_To_PDF <- "C:/File.pdf"
fitz <- import("fitz")
doc <- fitz$open(path_To_PDF)
nb_Page <- doc$page_count

for(i in 1 : nb_Page)
{
  page <- doc[i - 1]
  list_Hit <- page$search_for("cats")
  nb_Hit <- length(list_Hit)
  
  if(nb_Hit > 1)
  {
    for(l in 1 : nb_Hit)
    {
      annot <- page$add_highlight_annot(list_Hit[[l]])
      annot$set_colors(stroke = fitz$utils$getColor('black'))
      annot$update() 
      doc$save("C:/Highlighted_File.pdf")
    }
  }
}
```

The files are available here : https://github.com/ManuHamel/R_Examples_PDF_Annotation