# Find text position in PDF file

Tags: python, string, pdf, text

I have a PDF file and I am trying to find a specific text in the PDF and highlight it using Python.
I found [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/), which can [highlight part of a PDF](https://gist.github.com/agentcooper/4c55133f5d95866acdee5017cd318558) when we give the coordinates of the wanted highlight position in the file.

I am trying to find a tool which can give me the position of a given text in the PDF.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Python libraries which are able to parse PDF files?

Comment: hopefully this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971243/free-tool-for-watching-coordinates-in-pdf

Comment: Also searching for this functionality with no luck so far (would like to have it work via command line)...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.search_for) can find text by coordinates. You can use this in conjunction with the PyPDF2 highlighting method to accomplish what you're describing. **Or you can just [use PyMuPDF to highlight the text](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-annotations.html).**

Here is sample code for finding text and highlighting with PyMuPDF:

```
import fitz

### READ IN PDF
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    ### SEARCH
    text = "Sample text"
    text_instances = page.search_for(text)

    ### HIGHLIGHT
    for inst in text_instances:
        highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
        highlight.update()


### OUTPUT
doc.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```

Comment: On windows i can not install fitz.

Comment: @keramat there is issue with 32/64 bit version. you need to install lower version of PyMuPDF.
pip install PyMuPDF==1.16.7 worked, but the default one and latest didn't

Please look here for more information ;
https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/414

Comment: Thanks for this @cilantro Ditrek, Could you please let me know if there is a way to draw a red line box around that text instead of just highlighting

Comment: @SMP check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559033/1301888 and there's more info here: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot.html#Annot.set_colors

Comment: The above code needs a little help. Add `highlight.update()` right after `highlight = ...` Also, if the pdf document has more than one page, then wrap the `### SEARCH` and `### HIGHLIGHT` sections in a `for page in doc:` loop and get rid of `page = doc[0]`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 ''Bionic"  it works with `pip3 install PyMuPDF==1.16` ; even though I have installed libmupdf-dev version 1.12

Answer (score 5):

With the new version of PyMuPDF, some methods got depreciated.
Here is the sample code as per the recent version. Secondly, I've also added a comment for each highlight which facilities the user to transverse.

```
pdfIn = fitz.open("page-4.pdf")

for page in pdfIn:
    print(page)
    texts = ["SEPA", "voorstelnummer"]
    text_instances = [page.search_for(text) for text in texts] 
    
    # coordinates of each word found in PDF-page
    print(text_instances)  

    # iterate through each instance for highlighting
    for inst in text_instances:
        annot = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
        # annot = page.add_rect_annot(inst)
        
        ## Adding comment to the highlighted text
        info = annot.info
        info["title"] = "word_diffs"
        info["content"] = "diffs"
        annot.set_info(info)
        annot.update()


# Saving the PDF Output
pdfIn.save("page-4_output.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and have Acrobat Pro (not reader), you can try the old Component Object Model with Python or VBA.

[image]

```
import win32com, winerror, os
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT
ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule('{E64169B3-3592-47d2-816E-602C5C13F328}', 0, 1, 1)
avDoc = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.AVDoc')
avDoc.Open(src, src)

avDoc.BringToFront()
pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
jsoObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()

for pageNo in range(1):
    pdfPage = pdDoc.AcquirePage(pageNo)
    pageHL = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.HiliteList')
    _ = pageHL.Add(0, 9000)
    pageSel = pdfPage.CreatePageHilite(pageHL)

    pdfText = ""
    for wordNo in range(pageSel.GetNumText()):
        word = pageSel.GetText(wordNo)
        pdfText += word

        if keyword in pdfText:
            wordToHl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.HiliteList')
            wordToHl.Add(wordNo, 1)
            wordHl = pdfPage.CreateWordHilite(wordToHl)
            rect = wordHl.GetBoundingRect()
            annot = jsoObject.AddAnnot()
            props = annot.GetProps()
            props.Type = "Square"
            props.Page = pageNo
            props.Hidden = False
            props.Lock = True
            props.Name = word
            props.NoView = False
            props.Opacity = 0.3
            props.ReadOnly = True
            props.Style = "S"
            props.ToggleNoView = False
            props.PopupOpen = False
            popupRect = [rect.Left - 5, rect.Top + 5, rect.Left + 40, rect.Top - 20]
            props.Rect = popupRect
            props.PopupRect = popupRect
            props.StrokeColor = jsoObject.Color.Red
            props.FillColor = jsoObject.Color.Yellow

            annot.SetProps(props)
            print(f'Found {keyword}')
```