# Sclicing with pymupdf

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I'd like to mark several keywords in a pdf document using Python and pymupdf.

The code looks as follows (source: [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557977/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-in-pdf-using-fitz-module-in-python)):

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")

page = doc[0]

text = "result"

text_instances = page.searchFor(text)

for inst in text_instances:
    highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)
            highlight.setColors(colors='Red')
    highlight.update()


doc.save("output.pdf")
```

However, the text gets only marked on one page. I tried changing the code as described in the documentation for pymupdf ([documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)) so it slices over all pages.

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")
for page in doc.pages(1, 3, 1):
    pass

text = "result"

text_instances = page.searchFor(text)

for inst in text_instances:
    highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)
    highlight.setColors(colors='Red')
    highlight.update()


doc.save("output.pdf")
```

Unfortunately, it still only marks the keywords on one page. What do I need to change, so the keywords get marked on all pages?

Comment: Your indenting is wrong. At the moment, the save occurs during the loop. This means output.pdf will be overwritten by the last loop.

Comment: @Alan I changed the indentation for `pass` as this indentation was wrong. Did you mean this indentation or did I made another error with the indentation?

Comment: doc.save("output.pdf") is part of the `inst` loop

Comment: @Alan You're right, I missed that one too when uploading the question. However, it still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 major issues you had with your code:

1. Indentation
2. The start of the slice is zero-based

Otherwise your understanding of the code seems fine.

```
for page in doc.pages(1, 3, 1):
    pass
```

If you want to loop over pages, you would need to put your highlight code inside the page loop. In addition, *you are starting on page 2*, not page 1 because page 1 is represented by index 0.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fitz

doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")

text = "result"

# page = doc[0]
# for page in doc.pages(start, stop, step):
for page in doc.pages(0, 3, 1):
    text_instances = page.searchFor(text)

    for inst in text_instances:
        highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst) 
        highlight.setColors(colors='Red')
        highlight.update()
    
doc.save("output.pdf")
```