# How to highlight multiple keywords in a .pdf file using PyMuPDF library

Tags: python, pdf, highlight, pymupdf

I am able to highlight all the occurrences of a single word in .pdf file using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497309/find-text-position-in-pdf-file/52977595#52977595)

but unable to highlight multiple keywords in .pdf file. Here's my code

```
import fitz
import os


keywords = ["remote","setup"]
pdfFile = "\D:\Python_Scripts\Email Analysis\certification-ACDA.pdf"

for keyword in keywords:
    pdf = fitz.open(pdfFile)
    for page in pdf:
        text_instances = page.searchFor(keyword)

        if len(text_instances) > 0:
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(inst)
                highlight.setColors(stroke=(1, 0, 0))
                highlight.update()

            pdf.save(f"{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdfFile))[0]}.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```

I am overwriting the file after completing search for single keyword but getting this error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/Python_Scripts/Email Analysis/PDF.py", line 19, in <module> pdf.save(f"{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdfFile))[0]}.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True) File "D:\Python_Scripts\Email Analysis\venv\lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 4209, in save user_pw, RuntimeError: cannot remove file 'certification-ACDA.pdf': Permission denied`

Comment: Still getting the same error after closing the document by using `pdf.close()`

Comment: I can but the issue is i have to change directory or name for every iteration which is not feasible because i would be having multiple pdf files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to iterate the string using `for`:

```
import fitz

pdf_file = fitz.open("filename.pdf")

for page in pdf_file:
    mylist=["word1","word2"]
    for i in mylist:
        text_to_be_highlighted = i

        highlight = page.search_for(text_to_be_highlighted)

        for inst in highlight:

            highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)

            highlight.update()

pdf_file.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```